# NLog variable not resolving

Tags: c#, .net, variables, nlog

I'm trying to use variables in my NLog.config file. They work fine for static values but for some reason they are not resolving variables. I have a variable defined in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      internalLogToConsole="true" internalLogLevel="Debug" throwExceptions="true"
>
  <extensions><add prefix="my" assembly="Extensions"/></extensions>
  <variable name="test" value="${date}"/>
```

I then try and use the variable later on in a custom layout of a custom target (it is passed to a property called `Context`):

```
<target xsi:type="my.CustomTarget" name="custom" layout="${my.CustomLayout:Context=${test}}"/>
```

However, this is not working. When I step through the code of my custom layout `Context` is set to this string: `${date`. (Yes, the closing bracket is missing).

Custom LayoutRenderer:

```
[LayoutRenderer("CustomLayout")]
[ThreadAgnostic]
public sealed class CustomLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    public String Context {get; set;}

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Context);
    }
}
```

Is this a bug? Does anyone know what might be causing it or how to work around it?

EDIT:

I believe the problem is in the nested substitutions:

```
layout="${my.CustomLayout:Context=${test}}"
```

Is there some way to escape this so it evaluates correctly?